# JSF 2.0 return null from action methods does not retain the original request parameters

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF application with a particular page to show/edit the details of a particular entity in my system (an attraction).  I have a jsf page which takes the attractionId as a page parameter as follows:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="attractionId" value="#{attractionsBean.attractionId}" required="true" />
</f:metadata>
```

To submit the changes to the attraction I have this command button:

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="button" 
                    ajax="false"
                    value="Update Attraction" 
                    action="#{attractionsBean.updateAttraction()}" />
```

In the updateAttraction method, normally in JSF when you return null, the user is redirected to the same page showing any messages that might have been created.  However, since the page requires an attractionId, it gives a validation error that the attractionId is null since it does not automatically add the original request parameter.  Normally I do it as follows:

```
if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessageList().size() > 0) {
    return null;
}
```

But this does not send back the original parameters to display the specified attraction.

Can anyone suggest a clean solution for this please?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `includeViewParams=true` parameter to an outcome to let jsf impl append all declared view parameters, but I think this can only work if you also include the view id. You could try something like this:

```
return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() + "?includeViewParams=true";
```

Or you could define a constant including the view id in your managed bean:

```
private static final String SUCCESS = "attraction?includeViewParams=true";

...

if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessageList().size() > 0) {
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Some more examples for this param can be found at this [blog post about POST-REDIRECT-GET and JSF 2.0](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/post_redirect_get_and_jsf).